# Best practice to handle column level select grants in PostGraphile

Tags: postgresql, graphql, postgraphile

PostGraphile does NOT recommend [column-level SELECT grants](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/v4-new-features/#column-level-select-grants-may-now-work), instead recommends to

> split your concerns into multiple tables and use the
>   one-to-one relationship feature to link them.

Now I want my `users` table to have a `role` field that can be accessed by `role_admin` but not by `role_consumer`. Based on the above recommendation, I created two tables. `users` table (in public schema) contains all fields that both roles can see, and `user_accounts` (in private schema) contains `role` field that only `role_admin` must be able to see. `role` field is added to the `user` GraphQL type via computed columns.

```
CREATE SCHEMA demo_public;
CREATE SCHEMA demo_private;

/* users table*/
CREATE TABLE demo_public.users (
  user_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
);

/* user_accounts */
CREATE TABLE demo_private.user_accounts (
  user_id INT PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES demo_public.users (user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  role text not null default 'role_consumer',
);

/* role as computed column */
CREATE FUNCTION demo_public.users_role
(
  u demo_public.users
)
RETURNS TEXT as $$
  <code>
$$ LANGUAGE SQL STRICT STABLE;
```

Now basically I have two potions to set permissions.

1) The first option is to use table level security. IOW to grant select access on table `user_accounts` to ONLY `role_admin`.

```
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE demo_private.user_accounts TO role_admin;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION demo_public.users_role(demo_public.users) TO role_admin;
ALTER TABLE demo_private.user_accounts ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;
CREATE POLICY select_any_user_accounts ON demo_private.user_accounts FOR SELECT TO role_admin using (true);
```

The problem with this approach is that when `role_consumer` runs a query that contains `role` field

```
{
  me {
    firstname
    role
  }
}
```

The above query returns an error. This is not good since the error affect the whole result hiding the result of other sibling fields.

2) The other option is to use row level security besides table level; IOW on table level, to grant select access on table `user_accounts` to both `role_admin` and `role_consumer` but in row level only allow admins to access rows of `user_accounts`.

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA demo_private TO role_consumer;
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE demo_private.user_accounts TO role_consumer;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION demo_public.users_role(demo_public.users) TO role_consumer;
ALTER TABLE demo_private.user_accounts ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;
CREATE POLICY select_user_accounts ON demo_private.user_accounts FOR SELECT
  USING ('role_admin' = nullif(current_setting('role', true), ''));
```

Now if the user with `consumer_role` runs the aforementioned query, the `role` field will be null, not affecting its sibling fields. But two questions:

- Should we always avoid errors to prevent them affecting their siblings?
- If yes, should we always handle things in Row Level and never only in Table Level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For option 1, throwing an error from PostgreSQL during a query is not a good idea in PostGraphile because we compile the entire GraphQL tree into a single SQL query, so an error aborts the entire query. Instead, I would factor the permissions into the function and simply return null (rather than an error) if the user is not allowed to view it. One way to do this is with an additional `WHERE` clause:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION demo_public.users_role (
  u demo_public.users
) RETURNS TEXT AS $$
  select role
    from demo_private.user_accounts
    where user_id = u.id
    and current_setting('jwt.claims.role') = 'role_admin';
$$ LANGUAGE SQL STABLE;
```

For option 2: this is a perfectly valid solution.

> Should we always avoid errors to prevent them affecting their siblings?

It's rare to throw errors when querying things in GraphQL - normally you return null instead. Think of it like visiting a private repository on GitHub when logged out - they don't return the "forbidden" error which reveals that the resource exists, instead they return the 404 error suggesting that it doesn't - unless you know better!

> If yes, should we always handle things in Row Level and never only in Table Level?

I personally only use one role with PostGraphile, `app_visitor`, and that has been sufficient for all applications I've built with PostGraphile so far.

Comment: Thank you @Benjie. For the last question, what if only one role is not enough. Many organizations have users with different roles and with different access levels to available resources. I guess if we want to avoid errors, we always grant table level permissions first and then handle things via RLS to avoid permissions errors. Is it right?

Comment: I manage organization roles with RLS rather than PostgreSQL roles. RLS policies govern which rows a user may update based on everything you know about them (memberships, access levels, etc). I also use Custom Mutations a lot.